# LibreOffice/OpenOffice "kinda portable / static" installation on FreeBSD (webhost)?

Tags: installation, freebsd, headless, libreoffice

I would like to use a headless OpenOffice instance (to interface it with PHP) on my webhost's server. Of course I can't install stuff there with the usual package mechanism, since I am just an ordinary user. However, I would be allowed to run (more or less) whatever I want, and I have ssh access.

Is there a way to install LibreOffice/OpenOffice in some directory under my home directory, and also get all dependencies there? It would be advantageous if I didn't have to run the actual build on the webhost, since it would clog the server... But maybe I could manage to build it on some other FreeBSD host... I would want the build to be as static as possible, i.e. with as few outside dependencies as possible.

Can this be done?

For the record, the webhost is running FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p3 on amd64.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you may try to install [ports-mgmt/pbi-manager](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/pbi-manager/) port (it's basically a bunch of shellscripts) and use `pbi_add` command to install libreoffice PBI.

PBI packages contain all necessary dependencies and, AFAIK, can be installed without root permissions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try. Sorry for not upvoting;  I can't since I don't have the reputation yet :)